# Vertically align div relative to a sibling

Tags: html, css

I have a form and I want to display help text. The text might be a bit longer at times. I want to set a fixed width to the div containing the help text and make it grow by height. Then, to align the middle of the help text to the relative input. I'm flexible with the structure of the HTML.

This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wvb29/) with the form and the help text.

**CSS**

```
.form-parameter { 
     display : block;
}
.form-parameter label , .form-parameter input { 
     width : 150px; 
     display : inline-block;
}

.form-parameter-helptext {
    width : 150px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}
.form-parameter:hover .form-parameter-helptext { 
    visibility  : visible;     
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

All I found so far is how to align a div relative to a parent but not a sibling.

Comment: What browser support do you need

Comment: You say you're flexible about the structure of the HTML. Why not go with [Bootstraps tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips) then?

Comment: You're going to need some javascript to vertically center the tooltips sice I assume you'd want to position them absolutely so they don't mess with your form layout. I believe this is as good as you're going to get with a CSS only approach: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/Wvb29/11/

Comment: @Itay - if possiable all modern one's (IE8+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox)

Comment: @Brian Frisch - I'm trying to keep my external libraries to a minimum but it looks good, I'll check it out. Thanks. the Popovers also look promising.

Answer (score 0):

I set the width of `form-parametr` to 530px and add `position:relative` to it,and for your help div I add `position:abolute;right:0;top:0;width:200px` 
as far as I know you cannot align the middle of the help text to the relative input with only html and css but I think this is what you want beside the aligning help text : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/Wvb29/13/)

and for the record you need to set `display:block` to this div when you want your width to work,and you want help to be invisible,you've used `visibility : hidden` this way you just hidden that div but as you can see there is a white space that hold place for your help text,if you want to remove that white space ,you should use`display:none` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.form-parameter-helptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    /* This is what I added */
    width:100px; // add the width
    position:absolute; // set the position to absolute
 }
```

I didn't test it on any browser or webpage but the fiddle works fine.